# Apache mod_rewrite issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to send every request to `www.example.com/user/` to `www.example.com/user.php?id=0` using this

```
RewriteRule ^user/$ user.php?id=0
```

Basically, if someone is accessing `www.example.com/user/` with no user id, the site will default to `id = 0`.

However, when I type `www.example.com/user/` Apache seems to simply serve the user.php file, completely ignoring the RewriteRule. Any idea on why this is happening?

Thank you.

I should mention that this only happens if I use the **same word in the URL** as the php file's name. For example, if I were to use

`RewriteRule ^yes/$ user.php?id=0`

Going to `www.example.com/yes/` would apply the RewriteRule just fine.
So it seems that Apache looks for a file with that name and ignores the RewriteRule.
And no, adding a [L] flag did not help.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/$ user.php?id=0
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ user.php?id=$1
```

Comment: where you are putting the user id if provided? like this : www.example.com/user/12345

Comment: I do have a separate rule for that:
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]*)$ user.php?id=$1

Comment: do you have a folder call user?

Comment: sure
 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/$ user.php?id=0
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ user.php?id=$1

Comment: GREAT NEWS! I managed to test the code on a remote server and it works. So all the bits of code are OK. It seems that my laptop's LAMP install is to blame :| DAMN IT!!!

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^user/$ user.php?id=0 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

from: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Comment: Tried the [L] flag, but Apache still seems to serve the file without any $_GET parameters. Basically, if I go to `www.example.com/user/` it just says `Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/image-jam/user.php on line 4`

Comment: please post your .htaccess. you have a conflict with another rule that does not probably have the `[L]` flag

Comment: you don't have any other rules for example in your httpd.conf? what's at line 4?

Comment: Nope, no other rules. Line 4 is `$id = $_GET["id"];`

Comment: if you try something like: `RewriteRule ^test/?$ user.php?id=0 [L]` and you use: www.example.com/test/1 does it work? I updated my answer maybe the rewritebase will work

Comment: Yes, changing the word to something different from the PHP file's name does work. And no, the RewriteBase doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: I added the QSA flag, also i just notice you don't put the `/` after the user id so the `/?` looks for the `/` or not

Answer (score 0):

I think your rewrite rules are in the wrong order, and you're not using the `[L]` flag to tell apache not to run any more rules when a rule's been matched. Also you could use the `+` operator instead of `*` to match *at least one* digit in your second rule:

```
RewriteRule ^user/$ user.php?id=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ user.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, [L] flag did not do the trick. Apache seems to simply serve the file.

Comment: I can only guess that there's another rule on your .htaccess interfering...any chance you can post all the rules you have in your original question?

Comment: Don't really think there's a conflict. But I did post the .htaccess file.